# google map wrong size in polymer element

Tags: google-maps, polymer, web-component

I am using the google-map element and I read about the .resize() trick to fix the size of a google-map element.

However I could not get it to work. Moreless, it doesn't make sense to me.

In my application:

1. only the first page which displays maps renders properly. Another page which render a map will not render properly.
2. if the first page rendered doesn't contain a map, if I go to another page with a map, the map renders properly.

That is why I do not understand how this can be related to the core-animated pages.

Live demo:
http://nicolasrannou.github.io/webapp-core/components/webapp-core/demo.html#welcome/home

All the "Contact" pages contain maps.

The maps are created after pulling data from a google doc, using a template:

```
        <template repeat="{{row, rowIndex in rows}}">
          <!-- location -->
          <template if="{{ row.gsx$type.$t === 'location'}}">
            <google-map latitude="{{+ row.gsx$latitude.$t}}" longitude="{{+ row.gsx$longitude.$t}}" showCenterMarker zoom="15">
            </google-map>
          </template>
        </template>
```

Those "google-map" element are pretty far in the shadow dom and encapsulated in templates.

I tried to access then in the core-animated-prepare event without success:

```
  transitionPrepare : function(){
    window.console.log(document.querySelectorAll('google-map'));
  }
```

Is there a good way to access an element inside a template, inside a shadow dom?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On accessing inside a shadow dom, here is one citation from the docs:

> ...If the element is in another shadow tree deep within another element, you can't traverse into it easily. You can use `.shadowRoot` if you really need to poke around:

```
element.shadowRoot.querySelector('x-other-element')
       .shadowRoot.querySelector('#something');
```

On maps that do not resize properly, I'll first look at the timing: `.resize()` should be done AFTER the animation is completed.